# I am having a .csv file and want to convert it to array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, opencv, csv

I am having a csv file which I converted from .mat file and the size of the CSV file is 10161 and the it is stored in 10161 rows and 1 column.

I can extract the csv files when they are in 10161 columns and 1 row but I am unable to do the vice versa.

```
ifstream file("lbl_all.csv"); 

string value;
int s;
int result = 0 ;
while ( file.good() )
{   

getline ( file, value, ',' ); 

string( value, value.length()-2,1 ); 
}
```

But here I am able to extract it but it coming in diff rows and 1 column.

Suggest me a way to extract it and store it in an array of size(10161,1).

Comment: `file.good()` is **not** the opposite of `!file.fail()`

Comment: Since you are writing a parser, also have a look how to do it [using Boost.Spirit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1764367/1968). That’s by far the easiest, most robust and probably also the most efficient way. However, it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: boost::spirit is indeed a good parser but it would be overkill for just reading a bunch of strings into an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right your file looks like this:

```
value
value
value
```

Assuming this is the case you can read it like that:

```
std::ifstream file("lbl_all.csv");
std::string line;
std::vector<std::string> lines;
while (std::getline(file, line))
{
  lines.push_back(line);
}
```